# CKAN server down after installing ckanext-plugin extension

Tags: python-2.7, ckan, geoalchemy, geoalchemy2

I'm trying to install the CKAN ckanext-spatial plugin by following the step-by-step instructions listed below.

http://docs.ckan.org/projects/ckanext-spatial/en/latest/install.html#ubuntu-12-04-postgresql-9-1-and-postgis-1-5

After installation and configuration, I get the following apache server error when trying to access the site homepage. CKAN is currently unusable. Do I need to upgrade the version of GeoAlchemy or is this an issue with the extension?

mod_wsgi (pid=29881): Target WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=29881): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi", line 10, in 
    application = loadapp('config:%s' % config_filepath)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 271, in loadobj
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 320, in _loadconfig
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 454, in get_context
    section)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 476, in _context_from_use
    object_type, name=use, global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 406, in get_context
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 328, in _loadegg
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 620, in get_context
    object_type, name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 646, in find_egg_entry_point
    possible.append((entry.load(), protocol, entry.name))
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1989, in load
    entry = **import**(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['**name**'])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware.py", line 26, in 
    from ckan.config.environment import load_environment
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 17, in 
    import ckan.model as model
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/model/**init**.py", line 7, in 
    import vdm.sqlalchemy
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdm/sqlalchemy/**init**.py", line 32, in 
    from tools import Repository
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdm/sqlalchemy/tools.py", line 33, in 
    raise ValueError("VDM only works with SQLAlchemy versions 0.4 through 0.7, not: %s" % sqav)
ValueError: VDM only works with SQLAlchemy versions 0.4 through 0.7, not: 1.0.12

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate the important bit, the error message says:

> VDM only works with SQLAlchemy versions 0.4 through 0.7, not: 1.0.12

So it looks like you upgraded SQLAlchemy to the latest version somehow. This happens if you use the `--upgrade` flag when `pip install`ing something, although the instructions you mention don't say to do that, so I'm not quite sure how you ended up with this version of SQLAlchemy.

I suggest you install the vdm and SQLAlchemy combination that is in the [current ckan requirements](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/requirements.txt) which is currently:

```
pip install SQLAlchemy==0.9.6 vdm==0.13
```

and I believe this is backwards compatible with all ckan versions. (Remember to run pip with your virtualenv activated)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using the following command to correct my version of sqlalchemy. 
pip install -r /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/pip-requirements.txt.

This seemed to fix the error.